# JSON fetching to sharedpreferences have to load activity twice

Tags: java, android, json

The program i intended to do is to fetch a json file and store it in sharedprefs and then parse it using another function...

but right now i when i load activity it shows

```
com.razorreborn.csebeta W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

So i have to refresh the activity and then everything works fine....

Here is the code...

```
package com.razorreborn.csebeta;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * Created by Kiran Anto aka RazorSharp on 1/26/2016.
 * For more Info Contact
 * Kirananto@gmail.com
 * 9495333724
 * All Copyrights Reserved 2016
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private maincardAdapter mAdapter;
    private CardView Emptyview;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context = this;
    private List<maincontent> notiflist = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.Notifications);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                        "mailto","KIRAN ANTO", null));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "REGARDING CONTENT OF CSE BETA App");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));


            }
        });
        setupCollapsingToolbar();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        Emptyview = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view_sub);
        Global.orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        switch (Global.orientation)
        {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED: Global.Orientation = "Undefined"; break;
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: Global.Orientation = "Landscape"; break;
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:  Global.Orientation = "Portrait"; break;
            default: Global.Orientation = "Square";break;
        }
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager mSGLM;
        if(Global.Orientation.equals("Portrait")) {

            mSGLM = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1,1);
        } else {

            mSGLM = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);
        }
        mSGLM.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mSGLM);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefresh = new SwipeRefreshLayout(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mAdapter = new maincardAdapter(notiflist,getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        jsonFetch();
        jsonparse();
        swiperefresh.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
               jsonFetch();
            }
        });
        swiperefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent,R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.cardview_dark_background);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void setupCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(
                R.id.collapse_toolbar);

        collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(true);
    }

    private void jsonFetch() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading));
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            String NOTIF = getString(R.string.notif_link);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(new CustomJsonRequestMain(NOTIF, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                        hidePDialog();
                                        // fetching json to shared preferences;
                                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                                        editor.putString("Notifications",response.toString());
                                        editor.apply();

                                    }
                                }

                                , new Response.ErrorListener()

                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                VolleyLog.d("Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                //error.printStackTrace();
                                hidePDialog();
                            }
                        }

                        )

                        {


                            @Override
                            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(
                                    NetworkResponse response) {
                                try {
                                    String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                                            HttpHeaderParser
                                                    .parseCharset(response.headers));
                                    return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                                            HttpHeaderParser
                                                    .parseCacheHeaders(response));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                                } catch (JSONException je) {
                                    return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ).getCacheEntry();
        }
    private void jsonparse()
    {
        JSONArray notifications=new JSONArray();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            Object obj=sharedPreferences.getString("Notifications","0");
            notifications=new JSONArray(obj.toString());
        }catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
        try{

            for (int i=0;i<notifications.length();i++)
            {
                maincontent maincontent = new maincontent();
                JSONObject notif=notifications.getJSONObject(i);
                maincontent.setTitle(notif.getString(TAG_TITLE));
                maincontent.setContent(notif.getString(TAG_CONTENT));
                maincontent.setDate(notif.getString(TAG_DATE));
                notiflist.add(maincontent);
            }
            if(notiflist.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i("LOG :", "EMPTY RECYCLERVIEW");
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Emptyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Emptyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mAdapter = new maincardAdapter(notiflist, getApplicationContext());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_dsa) {
            Global.subject = "Data Structures and Algorithm";
            Global.subjectCode = "dsa";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_maths) {
            Global.subject = "Maths";
            Global.subjectCode = "maths";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_toc) {
            Global.subject = "Theory of Computation";
            Global.subjectCode = "toc";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_oop) {
            Global.subject = "Object Oriented Programming";
            Global.subjectCode = "oop";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mps) {
            Global.subject = "MicroProcessor";
            Global.subjectCode = "mps";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_scs) {
            Global.subject = "Signals and Communication";
            Global.subjectCode = "scs";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_notif) {
            Intent notif = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(notif);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_dsalab) {
            Global.subject = "DSA LAb";
            Global.subjectCode = "dsalab";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_scslab) {
            Global.subject = "SCS LAB";
            Global.subjectCode = "scslab";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_exam) {
            Global.subject = "Question Papers";
            Global.subjectCode = "qp";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_misc) {
            Global.subject = "Miscellaneous";
            Global.subjectCode = "misc";
            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OopActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.AppShare));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Global.AppShare);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mail) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","KIRAN ANTO", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "REGARDING CONTENT OF CSE BETA App");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_parents){
            Intent parents = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentsActivity.class);
            startActivity(parents);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting){

            Intent subject = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(subject);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to load the activity twice is due to the reason that it starts parsing.. before the volley finishes fetching the JSON ... to prevent this.... only way is to make the jsonparse work after it finishes fetching.. that is on getting response from volley..!!

Placing jsonparse() inside jsonFetch() after editor.apply() would work...

Then while No Internet... For it to parse add.... jsonparse to volley.onErrorResponse
and inside jsonparse..

```
 try {
      notifications=new JSONArray(obj.toString());
        } catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context," SORRY NO INTERNET CONNECTION "
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

change the toast inside catch to this...!!! so that it would show no internet when it cant parse...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Place the jsonparse() inside jsonFetch() after editor.apply() and write code to manage when internet not available.